# SSIS set variable at runtime

Tags: variables, ssis

Anyone know how I can change a SSIS variable at runtime?

I have a variable User:SkipStuff

I want to set this based on a condition during a for loop container

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a Script task.  Add your SSIS variable(s) to the ReadWriteVariables property in the Script Task Editor.

You can reference the variable(s) in your script using the following format: `Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value`

Comment: Some examples: [http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-use-variables-in-script-task.html](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-use-variables-in-script-task.html)

Comment: One thing I noticed when I did this: it must be done in the "Control Flow" tab (the main screen), not the "Data Flow" tab.

Answer (score 39):

Use Expression Task instead. In the "Expressions" pane, put the variable to set on left, then equates it to the intended value.

@[User::VariableToSet] = some expressions...

[image: Expression Builder]

Comment: This is a feature exclusively in ssis 2012

Comment: Video is unavailable

Comment: It only allows one variable, wish we could initialize/reset multiple variables in same task.

Answer (score 12):

Lots of ways really, but the one I use most frequently is to use an execute SQL task and set the result set to single row and then put the results set into the variable.

Comment: i prefer your solution better, it worked great for me

Comment: For some reason, when I do this and use the variable in an expression during another task, later in the package, the 'default' value of the variable is still being used, and not the value set during the Execute SQL task.