# Check whether a file with random name exists in the folder-SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, file-exists, script-task

I am trying to check if file exists in a folder using SSIS Script task.

If I want to send out an email stating whether the file is present, then ForEachLoop can't be used. 
Also, my filename is random.

```
Firstpart_Secondaprt.csv
```

FirstPart is constant while SecondPart is random.

Check the firstpart against the filename and if found matching then file exists mail is sent out. else file doesn't exist mail is send.

I used FirstPart_*.csv in the script task. But it wasn't useful.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve this in script task in ssis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx). This will search a given path for files based on a pattern which can include wildcards.

Example usage:

```
var foundFilenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\my\path", "FirstPart_*.csv");
```

You can then use this in combination with [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052864/ssis-set-variable-at-runtime) in your script task.

Comment: what will the 'foundfilenames' value if no match occurs ?

Comment: An empty array of strings (`string[0]`). So you could check `foundFilenames.Any()` - if it is false, there is no match.