# Saving Date based in flat file into variable (SSIS)

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I've a flat file with many columns, one of which is `Date`. Format is as following '25.01.2016'. I've many rows, and for each row date is the same ('25.01.2016'). Flat file is rewritten every day, so date changes every day.

I have created a `dataflow` to move data from `txt` to `database table`. Now, I want to add `Send Mail Task` and in subject I want to use that date (ex. Sales for 25.01.2016). For that reason I need to save that date in a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS set variable at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052864/ssis-set-variable-at-runtime)

Comment: @TabAlleman what you find common between those two questions?

Comment: All of the answers to that question can be used to solve your problem.   Personally I would use the third one (Execute SQL task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your file has the format as bellow

```
id    | product     |  dateLoad
1     |  dell       | 25-01-2016 16:23:14 
2     |  hp         | 25-01-2016 16:23:15 
3     |  lenovo     | 25-01-2016 16:23:16
```

the best think to save some text in variable:use **the Script Task**

- Firstly create a new variable inside your package in my case i created one and i called **DATEVAR** the data type of the variable is String

-Secondly add a new component called **the Script Task** see the picture as bellow

[image: Script Task]

-Thirdly we are going add some code inside  **Script Task**

- Click in the **Script Task** and select your variable in my case the name of my variable is **DATEVAR** see the picture as bellow

[image]

- Then click Edit Script in side the **main method** add the code as bellow

> String path =@"Destination of your file ";
>
> ```
> using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
> {
>   String line;
>   String[] sp;
>   for (int i = 1; i <=2; i++)
>   {
>       line = sr.ReadLine();
>       sp=line.Split('|'); 
>       Dts.Variables["User::DATEVAR"].Value = sp[2]; 
>   }
> }
> Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
> ```

More details see the picture as bellow

[image]

Comment: thank you for your replies with detailed explanations. Sorry, if my questions seem to be simple, but I'm just learning this SSIS. I've upvoted some of your posts, least that I can do for you))