# SSIS Report: How to rename an excel file in a specific location

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, ssis-2012, script-task

We get an excel file in a specific location where the name of the file may vary every time.

So every time we rename the excel file manually to "Report.xlsx" and then we have some operation to be done using a script task. The file_Path + file_Name is hardcoded in the script task as

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Desktop\Report.xlsx");
```

Is there a way to get the file name from the file location and pass it to the above code ?

Note:
The file Path is static but the file name will vary every time.
At a time there will be only one excel file in the file Path.
We are already using a **Sequence Container** so cant change it.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: A script that changes the name as soon as a file is put in the folder?

Comment: @SolarMike, yes that should work fine. One more thing, since we already have a script task. will it be possible to use the same ?

Comment: If you configure the script task to be able to write the variable, yes, that could be done

Comment: @Cleptus, can u pls explain a bit on that, i am completely new to this.

Comment: Sure, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056098/2265446)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you use the actual file name. Make sure to reference `System.Linq`

```
var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Desktop");
var fullFilePath = dir.GetFiles("*.xlsx").Select(f => f.FullName).First();

if(fullFilePath != null)
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fullFilePath);
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as using a foreach => file + with a mask. And then passing the filename into the script task. I chose the c# answer because you were already in the script task.